# Гибкая проверка строки на соответствие шаблону

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток!

Есть некие шаблоны для строк: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX, YYY/YYY, NN-N и т.д.

Мне нужно проверить получаемые строки из файла на соответствия этим шаблонам. Сейчас сделаю это регулярными выражениями, но вся проблема в том, что шаблоны  зависимости от файла могут меняться. И шаблон вида NN-N может стать NN-NNN. Каждый раз менять регулярные выражения это муторно, да и не всегда я могу это делать, а обычный пользователь не понимает регулярки. Как можно выйти из этой ситуации, какие ещё варианты есть для проверки строки по шаблону?

Comment: Если вариантов будет не много, можно через чекбоксы сделать. Если вы делаете не консольное приложение. Если консольное, вы вести сразу на экран список вариантов регулярных выражений и пользователь указывает какой шаблон ему необходим.

Comment: @WebMorda Приложение не консольное, ориентировано на обычного пользователя. Пока пришёл к выводу что придётся регулярные выражения собирать по информации из текстбоксов, чекбоксов и т.д. Большую гибкость не получится получить, но хотя бы размеры масок можно скореектировать :)

Comment: Можно придумать конвертер шаблонов в регулярки

Comment: @andreymal, можно и так. Пока я остановился на варианте что человек сам пишет какого рода должна быть информация, количество повторений и если есть, то разделители указывает. По этой информации простенькие регулярные выражения формируются.